# Transfer Ether from my wallet to another wallet

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets, myetherwallet

I have a wallet at MyEtherWallet.com . Is there any API which allows me to transfer Ether from my account to different accounts ? Does MyEtherWallet provides any such API's ?

I saw the documentation, it mentioned the params below:

```
eth_sendTransaction

Creates new message call transaction or a contract creation, if the data field contains code.

params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

But what is the URL endpoint ? How do I authenticate that I am the owner of this wallet ?

Answer (score 0):

MyEtherWallet already has the option to send Ether & Tokens. If you know the receiver's address you can send it via here itself.

[image]

Comment: I want to do it using API.

Comment: Sorry, your question was not clear before. If you web3.js you shall be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it through terminal if you have a full geth or a light geth node running.

You'll first of all run the geth node, attach to it in another terminal window.

Second unlock your account with this code:
`personal.unlockAccount(address, 'password')`

Than you'll be able to send the transaction, using something like this:
`eth.sendTransaction({from:'fromAddress', to:'toAddress', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gas:21000});`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer NO!, If you want to write your own.

You can use [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) to construct a transaction but you have to set provider(endpoint) for that. You can use metamask or use [infura](https://infura.io/)

**Using Infura:**

After signing and selecting the ethereum network(test or mainnet) it will give you an address like 
`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/id`
which you can use in web3 like 
`new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/id))`

**Exactly**
you can use these lines to send ether from one wallet to another using node or any js file

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/id")); //change the id here to your own
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:WALLET_ADDRESS,to: ANOTHER_WALLET_ADDRESS, value:web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")}); //change the 0.05 to the value you want to send
```

Answer (score 0):

`eth_sendTransaction`

Creates new message call transaction or a contract creation, if the data field contains code.

```
params: [{
  "from": "0x73BCEb1Cd57C711feaC4224D062b0F6ff338501e",
  "to": "0xfd6D55EA19bC58252384325Dd351370A28291f27",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 100000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": autoconfig/."0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

Comment: Run Full Geth.node /.Async.autoconfig.update.node.personal.unlockAccount(0x73BCEb1Cd57C711feaC4224D062b0F6ff338501e, '5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E)

Comment: Post/.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/id")); //change the id = 0x73BCEb1Cd57C711feaC4224D062b0F6ff338501e
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:WALLET_ADDRESS = 0x73BCEb1Cd57C711feaC4224D062b0F6ff338501e ANOTHER_WALLET_ADDRESS = 0xfd6D55EA19bC58252384325Dd351370A28291f27, value:web3.toWei(5000, "ether")}); //change the 5000, "ether" to the value /. to send

Comment: eth.sendTransaction({from:'fromAddress:0x73BCEb1Cd57C711feaC4224D062b0F6ff338501e', to:'toAddress:0xfd6D55EA19bC58252384325Dd351370A28291f27', value: web3.toWei(500, "ether"), gas:210000});